# Is it possible to have a technic modpack locally?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I would like to create a custom modpack for personal use, without needing to upload to the technic website. Is that possible, how does that work? If it doesn't, is there another launcher that i could use? What i want to do is replace certain mods in tekkit-lite, using a copy of the modpack.

Comment: From my experience you can just change the mods in the tekkit lite folder although make sure you backup the modpacks folder as it will be reset. Other than that have you tried multi mc?

Comment: Just a warning: the Tekkit Modpacks are "modpacks" as in not "just a bunch of mods thrown together". The mods in them are made compatible with each other, e.g. ItemID conflicts are solved, etc.

Comment: @MrLemon i looked around the modpack folders enough to know that much, is there documentation how to make configuration files properly on my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just wanting  to add a few mods then you can do this to tekkit lite. Go to %APPDATA%/roaming/.technic/modpacks/"name of pack here" and place the mods in the mods folder. If you do this, then be sure to make a copy of the modpacks's folder as it can be reset from time to time.

Other than that, you can use [multi mc](http://multimc.org) which allows you to have many different profiles as well as easily install forge and other mods.

Comment: I went with MultiMC and managed to migrate the profile from the technic launcher there. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible in technic launcher (build 204) by editing `%appdata%\.technic\installedPacks`.

1. Use Launcher to download vanilla or another pack you want to use as base for modepack
2. Close launcher
3. copy "source mode pack" to new directory in `%appdata%\.technic\modpacks`
4. in installedPacks create new block for your new pack:

> "My pack": {
>         "name": "My pack",
>         "build": "recommended",
>         "directory": "%MODPACKS%\Mypack"
>       },

5. in same file add new row in "byIndex" list

> "byIndex": [
>   
> "official-crafting-dead-mod",
>   
> "carovny-minecraft-magic-mc",
>   
> "vanilla",
>   
> "My pack"
>   
> ],

6. Start Launcher and your pack will be listed in modpack section.

Answer (score 1):

hey i understand your want for a custom modpack, there is a very simple easy way to get a custom modpack with just a few clicks (can have 200+ mods). one catch it isn't on the technic launcher, you have to use a launcher called "AT Launcher".

1. download the launcher  (The AT Launcher)
2. open the launcher and go to the packs page
3. scroll down until you find "Solitary Craft"
4. click the New instance button next to the pack
5. select the mods you would like in your pack via the pop-up window that appears within the launcher
6. wait for mods to download
7. play and enjoy

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a different launcher like MultiMC. The old Tekkit Launcher supported custom zips, but the new one handles everything automatically through the Technic Platform.

Comment: MultiMC now even supports those custom ZIPs, as well as import directly from Technic Platform

Answer (score 0):

What i did is for example i wanted a ships mod from a modpack(pirates at sea) and i wanted it in hexxit.
all i did to have hexxit and the ships mod together was go into the pirates at sea folder go to modpacks copie the ships mod paste it into hexxits mods then copie the config file for the ships mod and put it in hexxits config folder.

the modpacks also im pretty sure have to be for the same version of minecraft.